# Using the colon notation to generate an array and the ‘^’ operation to create the vector

Tags: matlab

so I'm supposed to create the vector
Y = 2  4  8 16  32  64  128  256

it is basically 2^(x+1) as in 2^1, 2^2, 2^3 and so on.

So my attempt is 
Y = [2:2^1:256], basically I want it to start at 2, end at 256 and increase at an increment of 2^1 but I keep getting 2, 4, 6, 8, 10... as my answer rather than 2, 4, 8, 16, 32... since matlab thinks I want it to increase at an increment of 2 rather than 2^(x+1).

I've tried many combinations such as [2:^1:256] but those don't work either.

Can anyone offer me some tips on this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The reason that `[2:2^1:256]` is that the `2^1` just becomes `2`, and so it's like you wrote `[2:2:256]`.

Instead, you can think of `[2^1 2^2 2^3 ...]` as raising `2` to the powers `[1 2 3 ...]`. The operator that does that is `.^`, componentwise exponentiation: `2 .^ (1:8)`.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that in a vector, thanks alot Dougal!

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in the function `logspace`. It can be used to generate any logarithmic progression. It's based on log10 - so in order to get the sequence you want, you might do:

```
Y = logspace(log10(2), log10(256), 8);
```

This should generate the vector you are looking for (`[2 4 8 ... 256])`. Eight elements, logarithmically spaced, starting at 2 and ending at 256. It's quite a general solution.

Comment: More generally, you can define `logspaceb(base, a, b, n)` to be `logspace(a * log10(base), b * log10(base), n)` for the same result.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor that is a nice idea - but it leaves the same awkward problem of having to convert the numbers at the ends of the range to logarithms. I prefer giving the numbers "as numbers", as in "go from 2 to 256 in 8 logarithmic increments", instead of using your formula with `logspaceb(2,1,8,8)`. It's a matter of taste. Good to show the alternative - thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yeah, I chose to keep the same conventions as `logspace` for sanity reasons - if I was to write both functions from scratch, I would use the convention you propose, i.e. `logspaceb(2,2,256,8)`.